# Unable to see sample portlet created using eclipse IDE

Tags: tomcat, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I'm trying to deploy the "sampleMVC" Project test as per the documentation but I keep running into this error:

```
INFO: Deploying web application directory H:\softwares\workspace\_liferay\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\sampleMVC-portlet
Jan 24, 2013 7:12:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/portlet is already defined
Jan 24, 2013 7:12:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui is already defined
Jan 24, 2013 7:12:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
```

Because of this i am unable to see Portlet in liferay Add->Sample.
Any help would be appriciated. 
I am using liferay 6.1 GA2.

Comment: This is no error, it won't stop deployment of the portlet. Try to redeploy the portlet, or post some code which would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Have you added the portlet to your Liferay Server (right click on server instance, "Add and remove" )?

Comment: @PrakashK this doesn't look like an error but this is the problem..http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/16869431.. This thread also pointed this issue...but no fair solution given.

Comment: @yannicuLar yes added but problem still there.

Comment: Portlet deployment can stuck in case of unfinished portal setup wizard. Complete sutup installation, it could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to solve this problem is to uninstall liferay and then install it again. As suggested [here as well](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/16869431). I also solved this issue after doing this.